# How to click a link in scrapy, parse some data on the new page and then return to the previous page to continue parsing

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to parse the data table at [this](https://www.signalstart.com/search-signals) page.

The second column in the table, `Name`, has a link in it with further data on that row.

I want to click on that link and add more data to `data_row`, a dictionary where each key points to the value for a `<td>` cell in that row.

My [code for iterating over the rows of the data table](https://github.com/metaperl/signalstart-analysis/blob/master/src/spiders/signalstart_spider.py#L34) works just fine.

But I need to enhance it to click the link, parse some fields on the details page for that data row and then go back to the previous page, `yield` the `data_row` and then continue iteration with the next row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use different approach:

1. Process all columns except Name for a current row and save result in
   some structure (`data_row = {}`)
2. "click" on Name link and use `request.meta` to pass your `data_row`:

   yield scrapy.Request(
       url=name_link,
       callback=self.parse_name,
       meta={
           'data_row': data_row,
       },
   )
3. Parse response, update your `data_row` (`response.meta["data_row"]`) with new data and `yield` it.

Comment: the part that confuses/scares me about this is that you `yield` the `scrapy.Request` - instead of simply calling `scrapy.Request` ... i'm not sure how this `yield` plays out with the `yield` I already am using.

Comment: In Scrapy you need to `yield` requests too.

Comment: UPDATE: `meta` is now preferred for middleware and `cb_kwargs` is preferred for passing data - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments